# Printing an array gives me more values than what the array actually has

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, cs50, sizeof

I tried to create a simple program that prints out the whole array but the program gives some values that aren't even in the array.  Why is that and how can I fix it?

code:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int array[]={1,2,3,7};
    int len=sizeof(array);
    for(int i=0;i!=len;i++)
    {
        printf("%i\n",array[i]);
    }
}
```

output that I want:

```
1
2
3
7
```

what I get:

```
1
2
3
7
-1483754768
32766
0
0
4195904
0
-953930857
32541
1
0
-1483754760
32766
```

So as you can see it prints out the values I placed inside the array but it also prints out a lot of values I never placed in it.

Comment: If you do basic debugging you should be able to at least find out more than you have. Ask yourself - what could cause it to print more? `len` is the wrong value of course. So what value is it? Using a debugger and/or adding debug print statements would tell you that. Effective debugging is an essential skill and it's not hard to at least get started.

Comment: `sizeof(array)` -> `sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0])`

Answer (score 2):

Sizeof() returns the size in BYTES of the array. So it will return 4bytes*4cells =16 bytes. Then because you are storing it in an integer variable it will convert it to decimal. What you have to do is sizeof(array)/sizeof(int) and it will give you the precise number of cells of the array

Comment: `storing it in an integer variable it will convert it to decimal` this is false

Answer (score 1):

sizeof gives you size in bytes. To have number of array elements you need to divide it by size of the array element

```
int len=sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have an array declared like

```
T array[N];
```

where `T` is the type of elements of the array and `N` is the number of elements then `sizeof( array )` is equal to `N * sizeof( T )` and yields the size of the extent of the memory occupied by the array.

So for this declaration

```
int array[]={1,2,3,7};
int len=sizeof(array);
```

`sizeof( array )` is equal to `4 * sizeof( int )` and if `sizeof( int )` is equal to `4` then  `sizeof( array )` is equal to `16`.

But in the loop you need the number of elements not the size of the memory occupied by the array.

So you should write for example

```
size_t len = sizeof( array ) / sizeof( int );
```

Pay attention to that the type of an expression with the sizeof operator has the type `size_t`.

You may use your approach with the calculation of the number of elements in an array the following way

```
size_t len=sizeof(array);
```

provided that the array `array` has the element type `char` like

```
char array[] = { '1', '2', '3', '7' };
```

because `sizeof( char )` is always equal to `1`. So `sizeof( array ) / sizeof( char )` is equivalent to `sizeof( array )`.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 problems with your code:

1. `len=sizeof(array);` sizeof() returns number of bytes of memory. One int requires 2 or 4 bytes of memory depending on the compiler. In your case, the array has 4 integers. Therefore, `sizeof(array)` will give you 16(4*4) instead of 4, which you were expecting.
   The solution is `len=sizeof(array)/size(int);` and this will give you the number of items in the `array`
2. This one is not actually a problem. 
   `for ( init; condition; increment ) {
   statement(s);
   }`
   I’m suggesting you to change your `condition` a little bit for readability in the `for` loop in which you should use `for(int i=0;i<len;i++)`. It’s not common for programmers to use `i!=len` Don’t get me wrong both ways work fine but most programmers prefer `i<10`
   I hope it helps :) Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the length of the array in the `len` variable. What you have to do!

1. The `sizeof()` operator can be used to find the length of an array.
2. Then `dividing` it by the size of one element of the array.
3. Show the `len`.

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int array[]={1,2,3,7};
    int len=sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);
    for(int i=0;i!=len;i++)
    {
        printf("%i\n",array[i]);
    }
}
```

Read more [find the length of an array](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-do-i-find-the-length-of-an-array-in-c-cplusplus)